# Performing lists of tests with F# using Xunit

Tags: c#, .net, testing, f#, xunit

I am performing multiple tests in F# using Xunit , using visual studio as my IDE, that have the same form. For example here is an example of some tests one might perform,

```
let add x y = x + y
//Now we want to test this
[<Fact>]
let test1() = 
    Assert.True(add 0 1 = 1 , "userMessage")

[<Fact>]
let test2() = 
    Assert.True(add 1 1 = 2 , "userMessage")

[<Fact>]
let test1() = 
    Assert.True(add 1 2 = 3 , "userMessage")
```

And perhaps many more.

This is a bit repetitive , so instead I decided to write the following,

```
let listOfTests = 
    [
       0  ,  1  ,  1  ,  "userMessage"
       1  ,  1  ,  5  ,  "userMessage" //this should fail
       1  ,  2  ,  6  ,  "userMessage" //this should also fail
    ] 

 let testMaker (in1 , in2 , out , mess)
     let truth = add in1 in2 = out
     Assert.true(truth , mess)

[<Fact>] //I think that this might be where I need to make changes?? 
let runTests()=
    List.map testMaker listOfTests
    |>ignore
```

This *sort of* works in that the tests are performed, except that when I run runtests(), Only the first failed test shows up in my test explorer, but not the second test that should fail. I have seen some code about theories, but the code is largely written in C#, and I am having some trouble with the translation. I tried using , 
     []
     []

As the attributes instead and simply go a "the type Theory is not defined". Likewise for PropertyData.

Comment: You should be using the `[<Theory>]` attribute, as you mentioned. Are you using xUnit 1 or 2? In xUnit 1, the `TheoryAttribute` type is in a separate assembly called `xunit.extensions` and likewise in the namespace `Xunit.Extensions`. In xUnit 2, it should be in the `Xunit` namespace without anything special needing to be done.

Comment: Also, the behavior you are seeing is correct - with one `[<Fact>]` attribute, you are running a *single* test, and as soon as anything in there throws an exception (as a failing assertion does), nothing else is executed, and only that one failure is reported.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev Thank you for you comments. I did not realize that they were in a separate assembly.

Comment: That is a bit irritating with xUnit 1, because theories are very commonly used; for that reason, they have been moved to the core project for xUnit 2. If you can switch to xUnit 2, you should probably do that.